# Actions class- Text gets entered at the address bar of the browser instead of Google searchbox

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to enter text in the google searchbox but the text gets entered on the address bar of the browser. The xpath that I have used in the code is of the searchbox on the google homepage. Following is the code that I executed :

```
package p1;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class ClickLink 
{
    static WebDriver driver;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
        WebElement searchbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sb_ifc0']//input"));
        Actions ob = new Actions(driver);
        ob.moveToElement(searchbox).doubleClick().sendKeys("Akash").build().perform();
        System.out.println("Text entered in Google search box !!");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception occurred : "+e);
            driver.close();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is a video showing the above code under execution : [[link]](http://screencast.com/t/ab2lXBlufbX6)

Please let me know the reason as to why the code is not working as expected. Also note that I want to use the 'Actions' class for achieving this.

Comment: Works fine for me. Make sure that FF is updated to the newest version and that you have the most recent version of Selenium. Any reason you are forcing the use of `Actions`? It's not needed here.

Comment: This is really interesting.

Comment: It has easier way to implement without Actions class. Anyway, logically your code should work. But it is entering text on browser's address bar. It's really interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Well the following code works fine from my end

```
package stackOverflow;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Ans {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@title='Search']")).sendKeys("Akash");
        System.out.println("Text entered in Google search box !!");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.close();

    }

}
```

You can use webdriver element locator(Firefox plugin) to know any web elements xpath

Comment: According to Java naming convention, Class name should be start with uppercase

Comment: To use ID and Name of element is recommended first. Though the above code should work fine, but I recommend to use ID of google search box as it has an ID as "lst-ib"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I worked on your question (although I am a beginner to Selenium). I just tried to create a workaround. Please determine if the code below works for you.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class actionclassgooglestackoverflowquestion {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //this code is used to fix the below issue
        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33190740/actions-class-text-gets-entered-at-the-address-bar-of-the-browser-instead-of-go

        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.uk/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='lst-ib']"));
        element.click();
        Actions act1=new Actions(driver);
        act1.moveToElement(element).sendKeys("Overflow").build().perform();
        driver.close();



    }

}
```